# Cannot use the `doc!` macro from the mongodb crate in the scope of a sub sub module

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I use following file structure:

```
├── src
│   ├── main.rs     // Macros from here
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── mod.rs  // Loads the user.rs file
│   │   └── user.rs // Should be visible here
├── Cargo.toml
```

My `main.rs` file imports the stuff like:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate mongodb;

mod models;
```

My `user.rs` file looks like:

```
pub struct User {
    username: String,
    password: String,
}

impl User {
    fn create_doc() {
        // Some code, but doc! from crate mongodb is not in this scope.
    }
}
```

How can I use my `doc!` macro in the `user.rs` file? I also tried to add `#[macro_use]` to the stuff like `mod models;`, but nothing worked.

Comment: You say `!doc`, but macros are written as `doc!`.  If that's not the issue, you have not provided anywhere *near* enough information.  We need to see the code that's failing to compile, and the output of the compiler.

Comment: @DK Sorry about that. But I wrote doc! in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mongodb crate (version 0.3.1) [*has no such macro*](https://docs.rs/mongodb/0.3.1/mongodb/?search=doc). The [bson crate (version 0.9.0)](https://docs.rs/bson/0.9.0/bson/macro.doc.html), a dependency of mongodb, does. You need to declare that and import from there:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never thought about that.

Answer (score -1):

The mongodb crate (version 1.1.1) re-exports bson.
In Rust 2018 you can write

```rust
use mongodb::bson::doc
```